# map is not a function (Rxjs) though import

Tags: angular, ionic2, rxjs

there were a lot of questions about "map is not a function", but almost 
everyone just did not imported the rxjs library.

In my case, I do the import, but the error is still there.

I work with Ionic 2 and this is how my package.json dependencies look like:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.2",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
"@ionic/storage": "1.0.3",
"ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"ionic-native": "2.2.3",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12"
}
```

So that is how I create my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }

    private dataUrl = '/node';

    getData() : any {
        this.http.get(this.dataUrl)
            .map(response => response.json())
            .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
    }
}
```

I also tried to reinstall the rxjs module, but still no success. 
Maybe it is incompatible with ionic 2 or the current angular version?

What do u think guys?

Cheers,

Andrej

Comment: Can you show the entire error message?

Comment: try with this also `import 'rxjs/Rx'`

Answer (score 21):

This is 2018.
I was having this same issue. This is what worked for me:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.http.get(url)
.pipe(map(r => r.json()))
.subscribe(resp => {
  resp = resp.json();
  console.log(resp);
});
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem.

I am using jspm with system.js. For me when I upgraded my system using `jspm update` angular2-http required `rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12`, but `angular2-dynamic-component@0.0.50` required `rxjs@5.0.0-rc.2` which is then what "rxjs" mapped to. I suppose because it was the newest version? I discovered all this by inspecting the `config.js` file that was created by jspm.

So apparently when I used the statement ...

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

... it was adding map to to rxjs version `5.0.0-beta.12` which is **not** the version that http was using. I had to change the line to ...

```
import 'npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12/add/operator/map';
```

... and then it worked.

Comment: thanks!.I just changed the rxjs version number in your import code and  it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

create file rxjs-operators.ts

```
// Statics
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
// Operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

and call it when if needed.

```
import './rxjs-operators';
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

getData() : Observable<any> {
        this.http.get(this.dataUrl)
            .map(response => response.json())
            .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please import map as follow:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

instead of 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import { Http, Response, Headers, URLSearchParams, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the map operator:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

If this doesn't work, try

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Please note that for versions of RxJS 6.x.x and above, you will have to use pipeable operators as shown below:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
        
@Injectable()
        export class LoginService {
            constructor(private http: Http) {}
        
            private dataUrl = '/node';
        
      getData() : any {
        this.http.get(this.dataUrl).pipe(
            map(response => response.json())
            .subscribe(result => console.log(result)));
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your service something like this

```
 public saveUserDeck(deck:Deck): Observable<HttpResponse<Deck>> {
    return this.http.post<Deck>(this.base_url+`/decks/save-userdeck`, deck,{observe:'response'}**)
  }
```

And your component can subscribe

```
  this.deckService.saveUserDeck(deckEdited).subscribe(result => {
    console.log("result " + result.ok)
    console.log("result " + result.body)
    console.log("result " + result.status)
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

import  `import 'rxjs/Rx';` has some issues with 5.5.2 version as for each import i happen to change from `import { Observable } from  'rxjs/Rx'` to  `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`

Comment: Two things: Your sentence is incomplete. And it would be great if you could either elaborate *or* back up your claim with a source.

Comment: @MrPaulch: When we import Observable like import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx' creates issues and we need to move to import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';